# SOAP on Amazon AWS - How to run it?

Tags: soap, amazon-web-services

I've got an API that's dependent of SOAP to be able to work correctly, but the site that I'm working on is using amazon AWS, and I found out that amazon doesn't support SOAP from here on  their note section: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

Is their any other way to load SOAP on AWS? The API I'm using requires SOAP to be able to get values from a provider.

`object(SoapClient)#1 (4) { ["_login"]=> string(17) "site-staging" ["_password"]=> string(9) "password" ["_soap_version"]=> int(1) ["sdl"]=> resource(2) of type (Unknown) } 
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /var/www/html/status.php:26 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://cpsandb...', '', 1, 0) #1 /var/www/html/status.php(26): SoapClient->__soapCall('getUploadCatalo...', Array, Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/status.php on line 26`

So from what I understand is that we're having issues requesting SOAP request from other url services outside of amazon.

Comment: What is your setup like? Is your service hosted on an ec2 server? Nothing is prohibited if it's between your service and a third party provider. The link says that the communication to **S3** via SOAP is deprecated. Nothing else.

Comment: @TJ- Yes correct. It's on EC2. I'm not too familiar with amazon. But the same API on a linux server is running fine, but when on amazon it just doesn't work. And I found that message about soap being deprecated.

Comment: It may not work for several reasons. Have you updated your security config to allow necessary ports (on which the provider service serves)? *It just doesn't work* is not very helpful - What is the error that you see? Can you provide the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @TJ- updated issue above with error code

Comment: @TJ- Just tried disabling the firewall on server and getting a "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host"

Comment: Can you ping/telnet from your server to the provider?